# Flow Designer Visual Flow Loop Help

Tags: lookup, flow, update, loop

Goal: I'm trying to populate a look-up field on the lead object based on a text field on the the same object.  I need to find the ID of the account object whose account name contains the text in the text field on the lead object.

More Context: I import over 200 leads a day and I need to populate the look-up field on the lead object with the client account ID. In order to do so, I look at text field which contains the name of the client account and manually fill in the look up field.

I'm trying to use the visual flow to loop through all non-converted leads where the lookup field is blank and using the data in the text field to look up the client account and bring the account ID to the look up field on the lead.

I've been at this for several days and I can not figure it out.

I hope someone can provide some insight.

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you go through the [Trailhead Process Automation Module](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/business_process_automation) which covers Visual Flows. You'll want to create a [collection variable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_designer_resources_collection_var.htm) to add your text string to as you loop through your leads, then run a query that returns an [sObject collection](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_designer_resources_sobject_collection.htm) of Account Names and IDs using a [Fast Lookup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_designer_elements_fast_lookup.htm). You can then loop through again to assign the values to your lead fields. At least that should be the general flow of how it would work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I took a look at the Trailhead Process Automation and those examples are  basic introduction of the visual flow.  I've tried over and over and I just can't get it to work or just don't understand the concept.  I'm very eager to learn how to do this. I would be grateful if you could get in more detail on how to accomplish this.

Comment: As I recall, there are some included videos that show the process for creating a loop. That's the essence of what you need to do. It's also covered in the documentation. You need to add each of these records to a collection as part of loop. Once you have your query results via the Fast Lookup, you can do the assignments. This should operate like the equivalent of what used to be called a "Flow Trigger". See the [Power of Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/en/events/webinars/power_of_flow) for more.